# SHA512 and SIMD in Ruby

Tags: ruby, simd, sha512

Intel processors allow to calculate SHA512 faster because of SIMD optimizations they have. I want to take advantage of it in Ruby. However, implementation of SHA512 doesn't use SIMD https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/digest/sha2/sha2.c does it?

Is there any way to unitize SIMD optimizations for calculating SHA512 in Ruby?

Comment: You could write one in C. How man hashes are you intending to do here that this would matter?

Comment: Reference code: http://www.intel.co.uk/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-sha512-implementations-ia-processors-paper.pdf  - as far as I can see the Ruby library doesn't do it, but if it were to try this, it would need to be designed to work on a range of processors - it would be a lot of work to add the necessary conditionals, detectors for various "levels" of SIMD available etc.

Comment: That code you linked to isn’t necessarily used for the SHA implementation in the `digest` module. When Ruby is built it will check for OpenSSL (and Apple’s CommonCrypto) and use one of those implementations if  available.

Comment: @tadman, 8 hashes. and 8 more. and 8 more.

Comment: @Dimon Give me a number here. Billions? Quadrillions?

Comment: @tadman, millions.

Comment: You don't need SIMD for millions. Amend your question with performance requirements and where you're at using the existing routines.

Comment: @NeilSlater, why? 32 and x64, that's it.

Comment: @tadman, the question isn't whether I need it or not, but whether it exists or not, and if yes, where.

Comment: @tadman, or rather, the current implementation of SHA512 is slow for my needs, I need a faster one.

Comment: Please, speak in terms of specifics. Can you produce a simple Ruby [Benchmark test](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) that shows what your performance is right now and what level is acceptable for solving your problem? "Too slow" is a meaningless measure. If you need to write a faster one, you'll need this benchmark to prove that your work is actually doing something useful and not regressing in terms of performance.

Comment: Stay civil Dimon. I'm asking a reasonable question here. If you insist on being difficult, I'll ask you a simple question, the Stack Overflow Golden Rule: **WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED**?

Comment: @Dimon: There are 5 "levels" of SIMD available, depending on processor: None, SSE, AVX, AVX-2 and AVX-512. The source file would only have to support 2 (one of which was "None") and switch between them at compile time. But still it is a lot of effort, you tend to find only specialist speed-is-everything libraries going to that extent (e.g. ffmpeg does this). I looked at the source for OpenSSL and instead those developers chose to use inline assembly for some parts - you might want to check the speed of that, it could be enough for you.

Comment: @NeilSlater: There are several levels of [SSE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64.  Anyway, the [Intel SHA extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21533954/224132) aren't part of AVX or AVX2; they have a separate feature-bit, like the AES-acceleration instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I don't see an issue because I need them for x86-64 which is SSE2

Answer (score 5):

Intel published [a paper on SIMD-accelerating SHA512](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-sha512-implementations-ia-processors-paper.pdf), in Nov 2012.

They say they got  ~8.59 cycles/byte for their AVX version, on a Sandybridge i7 2600.  They didn't publish results for their AVX2 / `rorx` (BMI2) version, since Haswell wasn't released yet.  I didn't follow the links to the source code; presumably it's C with intrinsics.

To implement it in Ruby's source code, you'll need to handle the case where ruby is running on a CPU that doesn't support the instruction set extensions your fast version uses, and fall back to a plain C or SSE2-only version.

**Your best bet might be to have ruby use OpenSSL** or a similar library to get hand-tuned versions of SHA-512 and many other functions.  Crypto libraries already have with hand-tuned asm versions for many different platforms.

---

With Skylake (and Goldmont), Intel introduced [new instructions to accelerate SHA-1 and SHA-256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692386/are-there-in-x86-any-instructions-to-accelerate-sha-sha1-2-256-512-encoding/21533954#21533954).  Unfortunately, I don't see anything about being able to use [those instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) for SHA-512.

Comment: `Your best bet might be to have ruby use OpenSSL or a similar library` -- for example?

Comment: @Dimon I didn't have any specific alternatives to libopenssl in mind, but a quick google led me to [a decent article](http://www.interworx.com/community/reviewing-openssl-alternatives/) commenting on some.  [GNUtls is the other major crypto library I've heard of](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Cryptographic-API.html), with a different license and API.  `gnutls_hash_fast` is probably the function you want.