# AES based non-cryptographic hash algorithm

Tags: hash, aes

Is there an AES based non-cryptographic hash algorithm?

I think this could be useful, as we have AES-NI instructions, such a hash could be very fast.

I'd like to use this for fingerprinting (so its output should be at least 128-bits) and error detection purposes.

(I've googled for this, but all I found is cryptographic hashes)

Comment: Is your reasoning that a non-cryptographic hash algorithm could achieve greater performance?  Try just using a cryptographic one with the zero key.  Or try using the final block of a CBC with the zero key.  These have the advantage of already being implemented so you can discover the performance almost for free.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: It's simple. AES has much more rounds that's needed. I've created a simple test, and it **seems** that only 2 rounds are enough. Compared to the 10 rounds which AES-128 needs, it's 5x faster. But I'm no expert, hence the question.

Comment: Yes, it is known that two rounds of AES achieves full diffusion.  So you can make a new cipher, AES-2, and get a CMAC with that cipher which would be a reasonable non-cryptographic hash.  I don't think you need to implement this to get a good guess of the performance - just dividing an existing CMAC benchmark time by 6 will be an decent proxy.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: I think that better solutions exist. For example, I've created a hash, which is more than 30x faster (~30GB/sec) than AES-128-CBC (~1GB/sec on my machine). The problem is that it fails some of the SMHasher tests. Maybe someone else played with this problem too, and already have a working solution, which passes SMHasher, while has a very good speed.

Comment: @zaph: I did. Fingerprinting and error detection. Not for hash tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692386/are-there-in-x86-any-instructions-to-accelerate-sha-sha1-2-256-512-encoding - x86 instructions to accelerate SHA (SHA1/2/256/512) encoding.

Comment: @ziesemer: thanks. The problem with this that SHA instructions are still new, a lot of CPUs don't support it. On the other hand, AES is widely available now, not only on x86, but on ARM as well.

Comment: @geza - understood.  See also, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15914/accelerated-hashing-on-consumer-grade-cpu .  Ideally, this would be a better discussion for crypto.stackexchange.com...

Comment: If you go to crypto.stackexchange.com then it would need to be a cryptographic discussion to be on topic. Perhaps ask about the fastest block-cipher based hash/mac (VMAC and UMAC will probably be among the recommendations).  You could then take the obvious round-reduced variant.  I really don't know the right stackexchange site for this discussion.

Comment: @ziesemer: I think this question is off-topic on crypto.stackexchange, because it is not about cryptography at all. We just have AES-NI instructions, which can be used in a way which wasn't intended. So AES can be treated as a building block of a non-crypto hash, not something which has anything to do with cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

MeowHash is a new (still not officially released) AES-NI-based hash function that is extremely fast and appears to be very robust for the functions you mentioned (but not cryptography):

Write-up: https://mollyrocket.com/meowhash

Repo: https://github.com/cmuratori/meow_hash