# "intel xeon silver 4216" whether the instruction set of this CPU supports SHA256?

Tags: cpu, intel, instruction-set

It seems that AMD supports SHA256 and Intel does not. I checked that there is no relevant information. I ask questions here just hoping to get a positive reply

Comment: There's a Q&A about which CPUs do/don't have SHA-NI.  One of the answers, [Are there in x86 any instructions to accelerate SHA (SHA1/2/256/512) encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277666) points out that Cascade Lake doesn't have it.  (Your CPU is Cascade Lake; Ice Lake Xeon is out now, but still really new: https://www.anandtech.com/show/16594/intel-3rd-gen-xeon-scalable-review)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) the list of Intel CPUs supporting the SHA opcodes are (among others) Intel Ice Lake (and later) processors.

The Xeon Silver 4216 is a [Cascade Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_Lake_(microarchitecture)) architecture processor which is the **predecessor** of the [Ice Lake architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Lake_(microprocessor)).

Therefore the Intel Xeon Silver 4216 does **not** support the SHA opcodes.