# Benchmarking ways to avoid processing duplicate messages in a Go concurrent environment

Tags: performance, go, concurrency, benchmarking

I have a Go program that receives TCP messages from many peers, each on its own go-routine. If I have already received a message from a peer (which is a []byte), I don't want to process it again. To do so, I set up a map, generate a checksum from the []byte, and check if that checksum has already been processed. I've coded some benchmarks to see which sync map performs better. In this case, I'm comparing a plain map with a sync.Mutex, the std sync.Map, and a third-party "concurrent-map". I chose Adler-32 as the checksum algorithm because it is very fast, but I'm not sure if it is the best for my case.

Also, I will be emptying the maps every 5 minutes or so to make sure I don't run out of memory.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "hash/adler32"
    "math/big"
    mr "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "testing"

    cmap "github.com/orcaman/concurrent-map/v2"
)

func generateRandomBytes(n int) ([]byte, error) {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return b, nil
}

func generateRandomKeys(n int) [][]byte {
    var KEY_SIZE = 1000
    keys := make([][]byte, n)
    keys[0], _ = generateRandomBytes(KEY_SIZE)

    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        keys[i] = make([]byte, KEY_SIZE)

        copy(keys[i], keys[i-1])
        b := make([]byte, 1)
        rand.Read(b)

        keys[i][mr.Int()%KEY_SIZE] = b[0]
    }

    return keys
}

var keys = generateRandomKeys(10000000)

func BenchmarkSyncMap(b *testing.B) {
    var m sync.Map
    totalLoads := 0

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        var i int
        for pb.Next() {
            i = mr.Int() % 10000000

            _, loaded := m.LoadOrStore(adler32.Checksum(keys[i]), true)
            if loaded {
                // wouldnt process message
                totalLoads++
            }
        }
    })

    b.ReportMetric(float64(totalLoads), "loads")
}

func BenchmarkConcurrentMap(b *testing.B) {
    m := cmap.NewWithCustomShardingFunction[uint32, bool](func(key uint32) uint32 { return key })
    totalLoads := 0

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        var i int
        for pb.Next() {
            i = mr.Int() % 10000000

            absent := m.SetIfAbsent(adler32.Checksum(keys[i]), true)
            if !absent {
                // wouldnt process message
                totalLoads++
            }
        }
    })

    b.ReportMetric(float64(totalLoads), "loads")
}

func BenchmarkLockMap(b *testing.B) {
    m := make(map[uint32]bool)
    l := &sync.Mutex{}

    totalLoads := 0

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        var i int
        for pb.Next() {
            i = mr.Int() % 10000000
            ad := adler32.Checksum(keys[i])

            l.Lock()
            if _, has := m[ad]; has {
                // wouldnt process message
                totalLoads++
                l.Unlock()
                continue
            }

            m[ad] = true
            l.Unlock()
        }
    })

    b.ReportMetric(float64(totalLoads), "loads")
}
```

These are the results:

```
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
BenchmarkSyncMap-12              1623816           790.1 ns/op      128010 loads         104 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkConcurrentMap-12        5105674           227.5 ns/op     1108898 loads          27 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLockMap-12              2663365           450.3 ns/op      331547 loads          26 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

I'd like to know if the benchmarks I've coded are somewhat similar to the real-case scenario, and also if there are better alternatives for what I need.

Comment: If it's ok to sometimes ignore a message due to a false-positive checksum match, CRC32C is probably one of the fastest things to compute; that's hardware-accelerated on modern CPUs, if you can use a library that takes advantage of x86's `crc32` instruction for example.  Otherwise, much newer CPUs have SHA-1 and SHA-256 acceleration.  ([Are there in x86 any instructions to accelerate SHA (SHA1/2/256/512) encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20692386)).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1 isn't secure against collisions if the attacker has time + money.

Answer (score 2):

With a 32-bit checksum the risk of [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) is very high (due to the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)), so it cannot be relied upon for uniqueness.

Notice the massive difference in "loads" vs. iterations in your different benchmarks - the first run has a hit rate of ~7% and the second one ~21%. That's because the concurrent map is sharded, so there are fewer collisions.

Either compute a proper message digest like SHA-1 or compare the message body itself (this can ideally be combined with sharding, where you can safely use adler32):

```golang
type Message struct {
    Data []byte
}

func (key Message) compare(other Message) int {
    return bytes.Compare(key.Data, other.Data) // make the message comparable
}

func BenchmarkConcurrentMap(b *testing.B) {
    m := cmap.NewWithCustomShardingFunction[*Message, bool](
        func(key *Message) uint32 {
            return adler32.Checksum(key.Data) // use adler32 for sharding only
        })
    totalLoads := 0

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        var i int
        for pb.Next() {
            i = mr.Int() % 10000000

            absent := m.SetIfAbsent(keys[i], true) // store the message itself as key
            if !absent {
                // wouldnt process message
                totalLoads++
            }
        }
    })

    b.ReportMetric(float64(totalLoads), "loads")
}

func generateRandomBytes(n int) (*Message, error) {
    m := &Message{make([]byte, n)}
    _, err := rand.Read(m.Data)
    return m, err
}

func generateRandomKeys(n int) []*Message {
    var KEY_SIZE = 1000
    keys := make([]*Message, n)
    keys[0], _ = generateRandomBytes(KEY_SIZE)
    b := make([]byte, 1)

    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        keys[i] = &Message{make([]byte, KEY_SIZE)}
        copy(keys[i].Data, keys[i-1].Data)
        rand.Read(b)
        keys[i].Data[mr.Int()%KEY_SIZE] = b[0]
    }

    return keys
}

var keys = generateRandomKeys(10000000)
```

Comment: Even SHA-1 isn't secure against collisions if the attacker has time + money.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).  If an attacker can guess what message someone else might send in the future, they can start generating a collision for it with a different message that has their ID number or whatever as part of the data being hashed.  Then once it's ready, send it in the right 5-minute window (between the OP's dup-filter resets).    Or in every 5-minute window.  If ignoring a message has security implications, not something that'll correct itself with a retry, use at least SHA-256 or SHA-224

Comment: If false-positive dup filtering is acceptable on rare occasions with just a performance tradeoff like a client having to retry after a timeout (with a different sequence number that won't also be filtered), you could consider a faster hash that's 64 or 128 bits long, like perhaps MD5 if security isn't necessary.  Actually, even MD5 is fairly secure against preimage attacks ([Is there a well-defined algorithm to find preimages in MD5?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/257293)), where you need to match the hash of an existing message, not just create two messages that collide.

Comment: Also, my first comment was wrong about SHA-1: it's still believed to be fully resistant to preimage attacks, which is the relevant thing here when an attacker can only control their own message, not stuff extra bytes into other people's messages to make them collide.  ([How secure is SHA-1 against preimage attacks currently?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/103061)).  But if an attacker controls a filename or text that another user might include as part of a message, then we're on thinner ice.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've been checking some benchmarks (https://github.com/jacobmarble/go-checksum-benchmark) and it looks like xxhash64 could be the best for my case? It's longer than adler-32 or others and also way faster than MD5/SHAx. Considering the number of messages I will be receiving in a 5-min window I've run some tests and the chance of collisions is 0 or very close to 0.

Comment: @Ivan: Sure, if you aren't even trying to resist hostile users trying to get other messages dropped, then a fast non-cryptographic hash is a good choice.  xxhash64 in particular has no preimage resistance ([Pre-image attack on non-cryptographic hash functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/96090)), so an attacker that can guess what someone else might send soon *can* very quickly and easily generate their own message with the same hash.  But that's unlikely by random chance with a decent non-crypto hash function (just the birthday paradox), so it's fine if you don't have hostile users.